# Materialize CSS sidenav in Apache Cordova

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, materialize, apache-cordova

I'm having some trouble to build the material design sidenav with Materialize css in apache cordova with jQuery. The chrome console says that:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).sideNav is not a function

index.html body:

```
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a href="#!">First Sidebar Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">Second Sidebar Link</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav">
            <li><a href="#!">First Sidebar Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">Second Sidebar Link</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse"><i class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i></a>
    </nav>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/materialize.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>
```

script.js:

```
$(".button-collapse").sideNav();
```

Comment: Grab the init hack from Materialize [link](http://materializecss.com/templates/starter-template/js/init.js) Then made sure it is last called in my JS. Putting it before the rest of the JS causes it to fail. Tell me if it worked.

Comment: Put the script.js under materialize.js

Comment: @Raymond solved! put the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code from this:

```
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a href="#!">First Sidebar Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">Second Sidebar Link</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav">
            <li><a href="#!">First Sidebar Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">Second Sidebar Link</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse"><i class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i></a>
    </nav>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/materialize.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>
```

To this:

```
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a href="#!">First Sidebar Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">Second Sidebar Link</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav">
            <li><a href="#!">First Sidebar Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">Second Sidebar Link</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse"><i class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i></a>
    </nav>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/materialize.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/script.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[jsbin demo](https://jsbin.com/kinocihohu/edit?html,js,console,output) It looks this works.

Comment: Nope. I just think you should use jsFiddle as it is better to read and write, yeah it's off i know but...